# How to break line after every 10 words in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, programmers-notepad

[I've a list of username and gmails and i want to break the line at after every 5 or 10 words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opkrh.jpg)

Please Help me this can save my hours

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please use code instead of images to describe your problem.

As to your question, you can open the replace window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> then select "Regular expression" under "Search Mode".

Then search for the following:

```
((?:\S+\s){5})
```

This matches one or more non empty elements followed by a whitespace five times.
And replace it with the following (just adding a line break):

```
\1\n
```

Comment: I've tried to adding code but some error occurred so that's why I've shared image. By the way this code not working when I run this code it replace all username with 1

Comment: Have you selected "Regular expression" under "Search Mode"? Don't forget the backslash

Comment: I've copy pasted and yes I've selected regular expression  under search mode, actually I'm doing in macbook air m1 codeditor software all codes are working properly but only this code not working

Comment: So you're not using notepad++ at all? You should change your tags accordingly

Comment: It's an alternative of notepad++ and working all codes so that's why I've mentioned notepad++ tag